# Moving Google Cloud Storage bucket to another project

Tags: google-cloud-storage

What is the best way to move an existing Google Cloud Storage bucket to another project?

I don't want to copy it outside Google Cloud Storage for the transfer, have two copies of the data or use another bucket name.

How close can I get to these requirements?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Moving a bucket from one project to another is not currently possible. The easiest way to copy the data would be to spin up a GCE VM and use `gsutil -m`. This will at least save the bandwidth cost of moving the data.

Update: there is now a [Moving and renaming buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/moving-buckets) documentation page.

Comment: It looks like that using a GCE VM is unnecessary. I just moved 2 GB of data from one bucket, to another (buckets in two different projects), no massive amount of data was transferred from an to my computer (I monitored it with nmon).

Comment: You can probably use the shell in the googe cloud console

Comment: I hit an error about the user identity that was automatically created to perform the transfer not having the permissions to access my new bucket. But hitting the last button a few times eventually cleared it.

Answer (score 9):

It's now possible directly from the console UI. Simply head on over to the [transfer page](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/transfer?_ga=2.156353147.-1967142849.1563369328)

or follow the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/moving-buckets).

Comment: As far as the Google Cloud Storage Bucket method is concerned, intra-project is fine, but not sure Inter-project is yet supported. It might be possible using the S3 protocol or a list of public object URLs though.

Comment: Can confirm interproject transmission is supported using bucket URLs from 2 different projects.

Comment: @steevee The Storage Transfer Service can be used to transfer data between projects - see https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/configure-access

Comment: The link to the transfer page changed: https://console.cloud.google.com/transfer/cloud

Comment: The link you've put for "transfer page" didn't work for me? Seems it is not a documentation link?

Answer (score 5):

Another way from the CLI:

Just mentioned the source and target bucket name that may belong to two different or same project:

```
gsutil mv gs://src_bucket_name gs://dst_bucket_name
```

I was able to do it easily which google SDK install in local cli.

Note — login user should have proper access to perform the action.

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/mv

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a CLI tool that can be used to move buckets from one project to another or rename a bucket in the same project.

Permissions need to be set up correctly to allow the Storage Transfer Service service account from the source project to be able to access/delete buckets in the source project and create buckets in the target project.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/professional-services/tree/master/tools/gcs-bucket-mover

Answer (score 2):

It is reasonably not possible to move the Google Cloud Storage bucket within one project to another project. However, you can copy the data within one bucket to another bucket.

Comment: correct - but you need to set the permissions correctly (give read access to project-[$PROJECT_NUMBER]@storage-transfer-service.iam.gserviceaccount.com) and accept the fact that the file-picker will not present buckets in other project even though they are valid destination targets.